# How to pass "weight" in completion suggest query in Applcore search framework

Tags: elasticsearch

We are migrating from OSCS to Applcore search framework and the requirement is to pass weight in our suggestion query. Below is our request which is working fine:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [],
    "includes": [
      "somefield1",
      "fqn_completion"
      "somefield2"
    ]
  },
  "suggest": {
    "suggest_fqn": {
      "completion": {
        "field": "fqn_completion.US",
        "size": 20,
        "skip_duplicates": true
      },
      "prefix": "unit"
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

Below is the response of the above query:

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "suggest": {
        "suggest_fqn": [
            {
                "text": "unit",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 4,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "UNITY,WI,United States",
                        "_index": "index name",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "asdasdasdasads",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                            "somefield1": "something",
                            "somefield1": 1134123000,
                            "fqn_completion": {
                                "US": "UNITY,WI,United States"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In Elasticsearch query when I try something like below, it works fine, and we get weight in result.

```
{
  "suggest" : {
    "input": [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana" ],
    "weight" : 34
  }
}
```

But when I try same in my request I get "unexpected token [START_ARRAY] after [input]" error. When I remove "input" and keep only "weight" then I get "[suggest] does not support [weight]". Does anyone have any idea about this?